# Why does a PrintWriter object throw a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java

I mean, if the file is not found, it will automatically create a new file by that name (unlike Scanner), right? Then what is the point of the exception?

Comment: Can you share your code for when you receive the error please.

Answer (score 3):

Please review the Javadoc API which states:

> Throws: FileNotFoundException - If the given file object does not
>   denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of
>   that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while
>   opening or creating the file

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)

Comment: So, can you please explain what this means.

Comment: @KaneWilliamson it's pretty self explanatory?? If there is an error creating the file, it does not exist, or you don't have sufficient permissions an exception is thrown.

Comment: Possible that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @KaneWilliamson Usually, the FileNotFoundException contains an explanation when thrown. Examples might be, you try to create a file with a name that is not valid (containing illegal characters), wrong path etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundException` not necessarily denotes that the File is not present. for example if the passed in name denotes a directory rather a file, the jvm wont be able to write to the respective handle and will report the same via Exception.

As Per java docs

> Throws: FileNotFoundException - If the given file object does not
>   denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of
>   that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while
>   opening or creating the file